# How to convert nested array of object into Json object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using **React or JavaScript** how to convert below sample nested array of objects into
JSON:
Is there any solution? for this problem in react? I try to solve this problem through map but, in variable it will store last value remaining child objects are overwriting

Here i want to bind Json data into Fluent UI detailList with reference of filed name later i need to export in different format like excel...
for exporting excel we have to call data by filed name thats the reason whatever nested Json data is there i just try making simple Json format

Fluent table example: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist

```
{
  "msg": "hello world",
  "success": "true",
  "Details": [
    {
      "group": "grp1",
      "personDetails": [
        {
          "firstName": "abc",
          "lastName": "xyz",
          "mobile": 12334,
          "state": "abc"   
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "grp1",
      "personDetails": [
        {
          "firstName": "abc",
          "lastName": "xyz",
          "mobile": 12334,
          "state": "abc"   
        },
        {
          "firstName": "abc",
          "lastName": "xyz",
          "mobile": 12334,
          "state": "abc"   
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

how to convert above Json object into below format:
Expexted Json format

```
[
 
  {
    firstName: "abc",
    lastName: "xyz",
    mobile: 12334,
    state: "abc",
  },
  {
    firstName: "abc",
    lastName: "xyz",
    mobile: 12334,
    state: "abc",
  },
  {
    firstName: "abc",
    lastName: "xyz",
    mobile: 12334,
    state: "abc",
  },
];
```

Comment: `[ "msg": "hello world", "success": "true"` is invalid JSON syntax as you cannot have key value pairs in an array

Comment: I don't think you can. `[ "msg": ` is invalid JavaScript

Comment: First of all - this is not a code writing service, so please don’t just go “how to”, without showing us _any_ attempt from your end.

Comment: [..] - is array, you can't put key: value straight there, but you can put object there: [{ key: value }]

Comment: Second, don’t just go pointing at your sample data, “have this, want that”, without explaining the _logic_ behind this transformation. It should not be up to _us_, to figure out what _you_ actually want.

Comment: @CBroe i am not saying this one is code write service, whatever i know the procedure or logic i tried but, that one will store last value remaining overwriting

Comment: The point was, _show us_ what you tried. _“I try to solve this problem through map”_ - okay, SHOW IT then. Otherwise, we don’t know where you’re at with this, and any answer _would_ likely boil down to writing it for you again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, part of what you are trying to achieve is invalid JSON syntax as you cannot have key value pairs in an array. Hence `[ "msg": "hello world", "success": "true"` is not possible.

However, what you could do is the following:

```
Details.flatMap((element) => element.personDetails));
```

Wich will take all the nested elements and return them in a single, "flat" array. You can then use this result to put it in a JSON **object** together with your `msg` and `success` attributes.

Consider reading more about JSON [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).
And more about `Array.flatMap` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

Comment: here whatever inside person Details object is there know i want to store that object in one variable like  whatever i mentioned in expected format, becz i want bind those object into fluent DetailList with reference of fieldName later i need to export excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for that, If someone facing this kind of issue you can go thorough below steps.

```
var array = [];

source["Details"].forEach((i) => array.push(...i["personDetails"]));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flexible and legible solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { msg: 'hello world', success: 'true', Details: [ { group: 'grp1', personDetails: [ { firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'xyz', mobile: 12334, state: 'abc' } ] }, { group: 'grp1', personDetails: [ { firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'xyz', mobile: 12334, state: 'abc' }, { firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'xyz', mobile: 12334, state: 'abc' } ] } ] };

const r = objectScan(['Details[*].personDetails[*]'], { rtn: 'value' })(data);

console.log(r);
// => [ { firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'xyz', mobile: 12334, state: 'abc' }, { firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'xyz', mobile: 12334, state: 'abc' }, { firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'xyz', mobile: 12334, state: 'abc' } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const result = {
  msg: "hello world",
  success: "true",
  Details: [
    {
      group: "grp1",
      personDetails: [
        {
          firstName: "abc",
          lastName: "xyz",
          mobile: 12334,
          state: "abc",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      group: "grp1",
      personDetails: [
        {
          firstName: "abc",
          lastName: "xyz",
          mobile: 12334,
          state: "abc",
        },
        {
          firstName: "abc",
          lastName: "xyz",
          mobile: 12334,
          state: "abc",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const items = result.Details.map((item) => item.personDetails);

console.log(items.flat());
```